# react TypeError: Cannot read property 'fulfilled' of undefined on Redux tool kit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I just compiled my code and it prints "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fulfilled' of undefined"

it seems like I have to add initial value for fulfilled but I have no idea how to start.

should I convert my .js to ts and add interface for the code below?

Please help me to solve this issue.

this is my slice.js file for Redux Tool kit

```
import { createSlice, creatAsyncThunk , createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        username: '',
        email: '',
        isFetching: false,
        isSuccess: false,
        isError: false,
        errorMessage: '',
    },
    reducers: {
        clearState: (state) => {
            state.isError = false;
            state.isSuccess = false;
            state.isFetching = false;
            return state;
          },
    },
    exrtraReducers: {
        [signupUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.email = payload.user.email;
            state.username = payload.user.name;
        },
        [signupUser.pending]: (state) => {
            state.isFetching= true;
        },
        [signupUser.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.errorMessage = payload.method;
        },
        [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.email = payload.email;
            state.username = payload.name;
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            return state;
        },
        [loginUser.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
            console.log('payload', payload);
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.errorMessage = payload.message;
        },
        [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
    },
});
export const userSelector = (state) => state.user;
export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk(
    'users/signupUser',
    async ({ name, email, password }, thunkAPI ) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch (
                'https:/...',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        name,
                        email,
                        password,
                    }),
                }
            );
            let data = await response.json();
            console.log('data : ', data);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                return { ...data, username: name, email: email };
            } else {
                return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(data);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error', e.response.data);
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
        }
    }
);
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
    'users/login',
    async ({ email, password }, thunkAPI ) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://...',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        email,
                        password,
                    }),
                }
            );
            let data = await response.json();
            console.log('response', data);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                return data;
            } else {
                return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(data);
            }
        }  catch (e) {
            console.log('Error', e.response.data);
            thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
        }
    }
);
export const fetchUserBytoken = createAsyncThunk(
    'users/fetchUserByToken',
    async ({ token }, thunkAPI) => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://...',
          {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              Authorization: token,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          }
        );
        let data = await response.json();
        console.log('data', data, response.status);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return { ...data };
        } else {
          return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(data);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error', e.response.data);
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript that “compiles away” to just pure JS. So reaching for TS won’t fix the issue, but it might help identify the error in your program. It’s difficult to tell, but the error you’ve included points to that you have a variable that’s undefined that should be an object with a fulfilled key. I’d inspect both “signupUser” and “loginUser”

Comment: Does it help if you re-arrange the file and put the thunks on top?  So that they are defined before they are used.

Comment: Yup I tested it and it's just the order :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions are all correct.  The only issue is the order.  You cannot use the variables `signupUser` etc before they are defined.  You need to rearrange your file so that the thunk actions creators come before the `createSlice`.

Like this:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk( ...

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk( ...

export const fetchUserBytoken = createAsyncThunk( ...

export const userSlice = createSlice({ ...

export const userSelector = ...
```

Comment: appreciate your kind advice. it worked for me